# Обнуление select Angular2

Tags: angular2

Есть реактивная форма, в ней ряд select-ов в которые динамически подгружаются данные с сервера.
Все select валидируются = пока не выбраны значения всех полей, кнопка submit не активна. При перевыборе значения в select, значения во всех нижестоящих select обнуляются. Предполагается, что при обнулении нижестоящих select форма становится INVALID и кнопка submit становится не активна. Но по факту она остается VALID при обнулении.
Обнуляю вручную все данные + значение value `this.userform.value.значение = "";`

Вручную изменить статус на VALID не получается т.к. это свойство только для чтения.
Как правильно обнулить данные? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если форма реактивна то значит у тебя обязательно должна присутствовать инициализация формы. Так вот бере твою форму this.form и меняем у ее значение нужно вам контрола. Тоесть 
`this.form.controls['%input_name%'].setValue('');`, либо так

```
this.form.get('%input_name%').setValue('');
```